# Installing gremlin server manually with TITAN DB

Tags: java, groovy, titan, gremlin-server

I am trying to upgrade my tinkertop version to 3.2.4 version. currently I am using titan-1.0.0-hadoop1 version. since it is not embedded with the recent tinkertop(gremlin) version. I want to upgrade.

I did following steps:
     1. Downloaded gremlin-server 3.2.4 version, unzip it 
     2. Edited the GREMLIN_SERVER_HOME/conf/gremlin-server.yaml and include the 
        following settings to the defaults:

```
           graphs: {
                  graph: conf/titan-berkeleydb.properties}
                  plugins:
                   - aurelius.titan
                   } 
  3. then in terminal I ran the following command
      bin/gremlin-server.sh -i com.thinkaurelius.titan titan-core 1.0.0
```

after third step I am getting the following error

**DependencyGrabber$_copyTo_closure6 - Copying - /home/titan123/Downloads/apache-tinkerpop-gremlin-server-3.2.4/ext/titan-core/plugin/jsr305-3.0.0.jar
Could not install the dependency: java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot get property 'mainAttributes' on null object**

Comment: @stephen mallette please give a comment on this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is going to be quite a bit of effort on your part. I highly suggest using JanusGraph instead of Titan if this is a concern. https://github.com/JanusGraph/janusgraph/pull/78 addressed updating the forked Titan codebase (now JanusGraph) to 3.2.3

Titan is no longer maintained, but has been forked by the JanusGraph project which has a lot of active development on it. The current release (0.1.1 as of this writing) is backwards compatible with Titan 1.0.0

http://janusgraph.org/

Comment: pantalohnes Thanks. It was really big headache to me from the last 2 weeks. Thanks you for giving me the solution.